# Is there an R function in the ranger package that can combine two random forest model?

Tags: r, r-ranger

Due to the size of my RAM, I decided to split my data into two and fit two different random forest models using the ranger r package. Is there a function in ranger that allows me to combine these two models into onefor prediction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the stacks packages to create an ensemble model. Alternatively, do cross validation on with a sample of your data to train a number of models at a time and find the one that performs best on a holdout set. Check out parsnip from the tidymodels ecosystem.

Comment: My models are trained on different sets of data. From what I read about the stacks packages, the models have to be trained on the same data. Please, correct me if I am wrong?